# implement of siftdown function violates heap formal definition?

Tags: python, heap

I am trying to understand the implementation of heap right now, and I look into heapq module of python.
https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py 
Line236 is the start of the code of siftdown, the strange thing is, it looks like a siftup to me, because it adds a newitem on the last element of the heap array and tries to move the last element upward to its proper position.

```
while pos > startpos:
        parentpos = (pos - 1) >> 1
        parent = heap[parentpos]
        if newitem < parent:
            heap[pos] = parent
            pos = parentpos
            continue
        break
```

It reduces the index of the current position to (pos-1)//2 and finally the pos may go to index 0. 
So it looks like a siftup to me. Do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a nomenclature clash. What they call "siftup" is sifting towards the leaves. Perhaps the thinking is that in a min-heap, larger items move "up" towards the leaves.

Their "siftdown" moves towards the root.

It's upside-down from what we computer people normally (?) think of as a tree, but it's consistent. And it makes sense if you picture a physical tree--the thing that grows in the yard and in autumn drops leaves that I have to rake up and dispose of.

Comment: OK, it makes sense if this tree has root below.